# HTML5 Canvas - Dynamically Drawing on a large canvas without lag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I currently have a script that lets me dynamically draw lines on a canvas. When my canvas is 500x500 the lines draw perfectly. However, if I increase the size to 2000x2000, the lines still draw but there is a lot of lag between each coordinate capture so the line does not draw as smooth as it should. I will potentially have canvases that are as large as 8000x8000 so this is a major problem. I was thinking one way I may be able to resolve this is to generate several 500X500 and line them up adjacently so that say for example I want a 2000x2000 canvas, I would have a 2x2 table of 500x500 canvases. However, as I think through how to implement this solution, I realize it will take a considerable amount of time to get it working, and I'm not even sure if it will solve the issue. Before I spend a lot of time trying this, I was wondering if anybody has encountered a similar problem and has any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try doing it via WebGl, and let the graphics card take most of the processor load, but it's a few steps more complicated for what you might have planned?

Comment: Although, I can't imagine what you'd need 8k x 8k for, (4k montior quad scren? If so I wanna come to your place) Is it not possible to keep it down to 1k x 1k and redraw just the visible parts on/off screen as you move around, push edges, etc?

Comment: Keep your canvas size reasonable--maybe 1-2 times display size at most.